# Textfile to Multidimensinal array Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, text-files, vb.net-2010

So am working on a program that tracks Bets for teams ...Theses are some variables

```
Dim dataArray(9, 6) As Double
Dim betTypeMATH As Integer
Dim betTypeStrings="Favorite", "Under", "Pick'em", "Over", "Under", "Middle", "Even", "Teaser", "Parlay"}
```

basically my code right now I have it displaying it right and writing to the text file correctly

to Write to a file I use This only makes sure that the number from the array are saved in a fashion of::(Go down below)

```
     Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("1 -- What is the new name of the new report?")
    NewRepName = Console.ReadLine()
    FileOpen(1, NewRepName & ".txt", OpenMode.Output) 'Creates the textfile
      Dim ReportCreation As String = Convert.ToString(dataArray)
                For i = 0 To 8
                    For j = 0 To 5
                        Print(1, dataArray(i, j))
                    Next
                    Print(1, "  " & vbCrLf)
                Next
```

2  0  1  239  0  239
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 1  1  0.5  56 -56  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 2  0  1  260  0  260

To display the array I formatted so it shows up nicely on the console I wrote a Subroutine

```
Sub displayArray()
    Console.Clear()

    'thirteen charachters between the beginning of the lines

    'Console.WindowWidth = 100

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Bet Type     # Wins       # Losses     % Wins       $ Won        $Loss        $ Net W/L")
    Console.WriteLine("========     ========     ========     ========     =========    ========     =========")



    For i As Integer = 0 To 8
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine(betTypeStrings(i))

        For j As Integer = 0 To 5

            Console.Write(dataArray(i, j))

        Next

    Next
```

which displays each bet type name on the side along with each coordinate of the dataArray corresponding with it's number
So favorite would appears like this with the textfile that is shown above

Bet Type          # Wins          # Losses         % Wins       $ Won        $Loss        $ Net W/L

========     ========     ========     ========     =========    ========     =========
2             0          1           239          0         239 
Favorite

Of course more align....
Am having trouble in how to get each number from the text file to the dataArray

I came up with this

```
    Using fileReader = New StreamReader(RepName)
        Dim numline As String = ""
        Dim num As Double = 0
        Dim dataBets(9, 6) As Double
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 0

        Do Until fileReader.Peek = -1
            numline = fileReader.ReadLine()
```

But here's where I get stuck on....

UPATE: Right now I get errors on the following code:

```
         Using fileReader = New StreamReader(RepName)
        Dim dataBets(9, 6) As Double

        For y As Integer = 0 To 8 'loop through each line of the data (expects exactly 9 lines)
            Dim numline As String = fileReader.ReadLine() 'read a line from the file
            Dim parts() As String = numline.Split(" "c) 'split the line in to an array of strings on spaces
            For x As Integer = 0 To 5 'loop through 6 columns
                Dim value As Double = Convert.ToDouble(parts(x)) 'read the column and turn it back in to an integer
                dataBets(x, y) = value 'stuff it back in to the array
            Next
        Next
```

With the line:  Dim value As Double = Convert.ToDouble(parts(x)) or with  Dim value As Double = Integer.parse(parts(x))
with the following error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: You are going to want to split `numline` on spaces, and loop though the results.  Just keep `i` and `j` updated as you loop through rows in the file, and columns in `numlines` and update the array values at those indecis with the value returned from `Integer.Parse` to turn the string back in to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Something akin to this pseudocode should work.
It assumes a very strict file format, so you may want to add more error checking to make sure it is valid.
It loops though 9 lines of 6 columns, reading a string for each line, and splitting it on spaces. It takes a split value from the line for the current column, turns it in to an integer, and places in the current array position.

```
for y as integer = 0 to 8 'loop through each line of the data (expects exactly 9 lines)
    dim numline as string = filereader.ReadLine() 'read a line from the file
    dim parts() as string = numLine.Split(" "c) 'split the line in to an array of strings on spaces
    for x as integer = 0 to 5 'loop through 6 columns
        dim value as integer = integer.parse(parts(x)) 'read the column and turn it back in to an integer
        dataBets(x,y) = value 'stuff it back in to the array
    next
next
```

Comment: Well right now it sort of runs... I get the numline to read the whole line but when it comes to parts() as string it does not split it properly. It splits the array as such:
parts(1) = 2
parts(2)= " "
parts(3)= " "
parts(4)="0"
so on and so forth with the example I gave... am trying to figure out how I can just get the individual numbers

Comment: Something isn't right with your split statement.  Breaking in spaces will give you what you want.

Comment: Okay I get an error of 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."
on the line where - Dim value as integer = integer.parse(parts(x))
I have tried to do Convert.ToDouble(parts(x) for the array and it threw the same exception I am confuse why it doesn't turn the string into a double or integer

Comment: Can you update your question and add your new code so I can see what you are doing?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice you had a decimal in your data file. Try changing all the references of 'integer' to 'decimal'  in the line that does the conversions.